# frame of different objects in IBOutletCollection returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iboutletcollection

I created 8 different objects (4 pairs of UIImageView and textview) on the storyboard and connect each of them to a IBOutletCollection, but when I do this

```
for (UIView *element in infoElements) {
    NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(element.frame));
}
```

it returns

```
frame: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

[infoElements count] returns correctly 8

and

```
NSLog(@"element: %@", element);
```

returns correctly the object, only the frame is missing. I only need the position (x and y) of every object in the IBOutletCollection.

The initialization is like this:

```
@interface infoViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *infoElements;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *infoElements;
```

I googled it for many hours now and didn't find that anyone had the same problem (except [this unanswered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015365/position-of-uibutton-in-iboutletcollection)), so I think that I'm just doing something wrong

***Edit***

Just to clarify, the objects in the IBOutletCollection aren't in the position 0,0 and are bigger than 0,0

Comment: Where are you running this code? In `-init`, `-viewDidLoad`, or elsewhere? Can you please post the actual output when you log out the element itself?

Comment: -viewDidLoad, the output of the first element is: element: <UIImageView: 0x813f4e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0x813f540>>

Comment: That's your problem.  Do it in -viewWillAppear, instead.

Comment: same result in -viewWillAppear

Comment: Just to clarify, why do you have infoElements declared twice and are you connecting the uiviews to the property IBOutletCollection?

Comment: its just because in case the ivar fails (it does sometimes), already try it with either of them, and the prove that i'm connecting the elements properly is the output of my log above and the number of elements of the array (8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are using Auto Layout. In this case the frame won't be set until layoutSubviews has been called.

So if you need to get the frame you can do that in `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`. However, if you are planning on manipulating the frame you should do that with Constraints when using Auto Layout.

Another option would be to just turn off Auto Layout in your Storyboard.

Comment: at last, thanks men, it works calling in that method, the auto layout was the problem. Just a Side note, i was able to manipulate the object using: element.layer.position = CGPointMake(200, y); with QuartzCore framework